# Generate Classes Using JSON data as a reference

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm consuming REST-like API which returns JSON objects. I can deserialize those objects to C# objects, but I'd like to have strongly typed solution.

Is there any tool that can generate classes using JSON objects as reference?

Comment: This isn't really specific to REST services--please consider editing the title and tagging to remove references to REST.

Comment: First Google hit for `generate c# code from json`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066550/is-there-a-tool-to-generate-c-sharp-classes-based-off-a-json-string

Comment: So there is no any common way to describe APIs and generate proxies, like WSDL for SOAP services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page has some links to tools to generate C# classes from JSON:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233698/Consuming-a-Json-WebService-from-a-Csharp-or-VB-Ap